# How to stop display turn on and consuming battery power, when using Headphones remote control or volume button?

Tags: lock-screens, battery-life, buttons, remote-control, standby

I don't know if this depends on the music player (I'm using mort player music) or standby screen (I have widgetlocker app as lockscreen), I don't see any options in these apps to change this. In Android 2.3.4 (rooted) I have set turn off Display after 30 sec.

When I jump to next/forward song via remote control button of my headset, every time the display turns on for 30 sec. For the volume buttons the same.

Is there a way to stop this behaviour and save battery power. E.g. only turn on screen when pushing HOME or POWER button when in standby? Any apps like *tasker* able to manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it depends upon the music player app. Have you tried using another music player?

In my case, I didn't encounter this issue. I have used Samsung Galaxy 3 with several music players including stock player and also with a Bluetooth headset.

I think the app itself is the cause for this, which is causing screen wake-up on next/previous, and in my opinion is a poor implementation.

I don't know of any apps which allow to change the screen on behavior like this. It may be available in Cyanogen-mod perhaps.